# React Typescript Redux-Toolkit - integrate redux state with existing ES2015 Classses based React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm having some trouble integrating React Redux. When I attempt to `mapStateToProps` and utilize the state, I receive errors that `Property 'token' does not exist on type ReadOnly <state>`.

I found another post that was similar but it seemed to imply that you don't need a constructor anymore. I believe removing the constructor would remove the components local state properties as well as the bind call that is made in the constructor, which I want to *merge* with not remove and overwrite. [Link to stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51074355/cannot-assign-to-state-because-it-is-a-constant-or-a-read-only-property)

```
interface Props {
  user: User | null
  sidebarSelectedIndex: string | null
  classes: any,
  token: any
}

interface State {
}


class TopBar extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props){
     super(props);
     this.handleListItemClick = this.handleListItemClick.bind(this);
  }
  //..some other functions
  render(){
     const { token } = this.state;
     if (token === ''){
       //return unauthenticated JSX nav menu
     }//endif
     else {
       //return authenticated JSX nav menu
     }
  }//end render

}//end TopBar Class
...

//trying to get the slice I made, user-slice, and its field "token" (for JWT) for use here

const mapStateToProps = (state:any) => ({
  token: state.user.token
})

let WrappedTopBar = withStyles(useStyles)(TopBar);
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WrappedTopBar);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is in casting `state` in `mapStateToProps` as `any`. Try to cast `state` as `RootState`. Read more about `RootState` and getting it from root reducer in [official RTK documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type).

Answer (score -1):

reduxjs/toolkit actually mapStateToProps passes the states through props So you have to use it like this:

```
this.props.token
```